# i7-7700HQ: What temperatures are fully safe to operate in the long run?

Tags: cpu, fan, temperature

[According to the public spec sheet](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97185/intel-core-i7-7700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html#tab-blade-1-0-6), the maximum temperature the CPU can be and be guaranteed to stay working is 100ºC.

I want to save some more on battery when doing some light work on my PC by reducing the fan use only while it is safe in the long run.
From the spec sheet, it is safe up to 100ºC for the short run but how high can it go to be safe in the long run? Is it safe to allow fans off until 70ºC, for example?
Would having fans reving up to 40% at around 75ºC and then, at 80ºC+ revving as the default? 70% at 80ºC, 90% at 85ºC, 100% at 90ºC+.

I already got some information but there is some contradiction (on what actual temperature), omission or just plain saying when it is the dangerous temperature (>100ºC)...

1. [Hint 1](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/got-a-new-rog-laptop-i7-7700hq-what-are-safe-temps-for-full-load.3212525/) says 91ºC is quite hot already.
2. [Hint 2](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/cpu-temperature-i7-7700hq.3325767/post-20302052) says below 90ºC is always safe.
3. [On quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-93-C-max-temperature-okay-for-the-laptop-CPU-i7-7700HQ) I read people mentioning 88ºC, 92ºC...
4. [This reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/intel/comments/6fs2vw/i7_7700hq_operating_temps_question/dikk1mu/) state that 82ºC is perfectly fine (long run
   too?) and "comfortable" for the CPU.
5. [This answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/90oxer/safe_temperatures_for_laptop_cpu/e2s1014/) appears to state 90ºC is normal but doesn't mention
   long run results.
6. [Then this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/90oxer/safe_temperatures_for_laptop_cpu/e2s68op/) appears to state 80ºC for maintaining a high
   temperature as a good option for long run.

Notes:

1. I already employ other saving measures, it just happens the next one
   I can do to save is in the fan consumption. Please don't answer
   about practicality, this is really the next in my list.
2. Idle temperature is fans off and 45-55ºC.
3. Fans' air path is clean and clear.

Comment: Elephant in the room; why not just let the motherboard manage the fan speeds with a power saving profile set in the BIOS?

Comment: Looks like you already did a good study (nice link gathering) and can make an enlightened decision based on it. Unfortunately, you will face other unknown variables such as your CPU temperature resistance, the fan efficiency, etc... Then I don't think you can get a definitive answer to your question. Maybe ask the CPU manufacturer?

Comment: You are not going to save very much power by doing what you describe because you will use more power to cool your CPU when it is hot enough to require it.  Due to the fact you will be running the fan longer and faster at that point.  You will gain a few minutes of battery life by doing what you describe.